# What is wrong with my code? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "npcId"

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "npcId"
I get that when I try to run it.

What is wrong?
Pretty much what the class does is reads and packs the unPacked definitions of NPC's into a file, but it is not packing correctly. (See below for format I'm using)

The class:

```
package com.rs.utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.rs.game.npc.combat.NPCCombatDefinitions;

// Referenced classes of package com.rs.utils:
//            Logger

public final class NPCCombatDefinitionsL
{

    public static void init()
    {
        if((new File("data/npcs/packedCombatDefinitions.ncd")).exists())
            loadPackedNPCCombatDefinitions();
        else
            loadUnpackedNPCCombatDefinitions();
    }

    public static NPCCombatDefinitions getNPCCombatDefinitions(int npcId)
    {
        NPCCombatDefinitions def = (NPCCombatDefinitions)npcCombatDefinitions.get(Integer.valueOf(npcId));
        if(def == null)
            return DEFAULT_DEFINITION;
        else
            return def;
    }

    private static void loadUnpackedNPCCombatDefinitions()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Logger.log("NPCCombatDefinitionsL", "Packing npc combat definitions...");
        try
        {
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data/npcs/packedCombatDefinitions.ncd"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/npcs/unpackedCombatDefinitionsList.txt"));
            do
            {
                String line = in.readLine();
                count++;
                if(line == null)
                    break;
                if(!line.startsWith("//"))
                {
                    String splitedLine[] = line.split(" - ", 2);
                    if(splitedLine.length != 2)
                        throw new RuntimeException((new StringBuilder("Invalid NPC Combat Definitions line: ")).append(count).append(", ").append(line).toString());
                    int npcId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[0]);
                    String splitedLine2[] = splitedLine[1].split(" ", 12);
                    if(splitedLine2.length != 12)
                        throw new RuntimeException((new StringBuilder("Invalid NPC Combat Definitions line: ")).append(count).append(", ").append(line).toString());
                    int hitpoints = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[0]);
                    int attackAnim = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[1]);
                    int defenceAnim = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[2]);
                    int deathAnim = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[3]);
                    int attackDelay = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[4]);
                    int deathDelay = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[5]);
                    int respawnDelay = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[6]);
                    int maxHit = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[7]);
                    int attackStyle;
                    if(splitedLine2[8].equalsIgnoreCase("MELEE"))
                        attackStyle = 0;
                    else
                    if(splitedLine2[8].equalsIgnoreCase("RANGE"))
                        attackStyle = 1;
                    else
                    if(splitedLine2[8].equalsIgnoreCase("MAGE"))
                        attackStyle = 2;
                    else
                    if(splitedLine2[8].equalsIgnoreCase("SPECIAL"))
                        attackStyle = 3;
                    else
                    if(splitedLine2[8].equalsIgnoreCase("SPECIAL2"))
                        attackStyle = 4;
                    else
                        throw new RuntimeException((new StringBuilder("Invalid NPC Combat Definitions line: ")).append(line).toString());
                    int attackGfx = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[9]);
                    int attackProjectile = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine2[10]);
                    int agressivenessType;
                    if(splitedLine2[11].equalsIgnoreCase("PASSIVE"))
                        agressivenessType = 0;
                    else
                    if(splitedLine2[11].equalsIgnoreCase("AGRESSIVE"))
                        agressivenessType = 1;
                    else
                        throw new RuntimeException((new StringBuilder("Invalid NPC Combat Definitions line: ")).append(line).toString());
                    out.writeShort(npcId);
                    out.writeShort(hitpoints);
                    out.writeShort(attackAnim);
                    out.writeShort(defenceAnim);
                    out.writeShort(deathAnim);
                    out.writeByte(attackDelay);
                    out.writeByte(deathDelay);
                    out.writeInt(respawnDelay);
                    out.writeShort(maxHit);
                    out.writeByte(attackStyle);
                    out.writeShort(attackGfx);
                    out.writeShort(attackProjectile);
                    out.writeByte(agressivenessType);
                    npcCombatDefinitions.put(Integer.valueOf(npcId), new NPCCombatDefinitions(hitpoints, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackDelay, deathDelay, respawnDelay, maxHit, attackStyle, attackGfx, attackProjectile, agressivenessType));
                }
            } while(true);
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void loadPackedNPCCombatDefinitions()
    {
        try
        {
            RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("data/npcs/packedCombatDefinitions.ncd", "r");
            FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
            int npcId;
            int hitpoints;
            int attackAnim;
            int defenceAnim;
            int deathAnim;
            int attackDelay;
            int deathDelay;
            int respawnDelay;
            int maxHit;
            int attackStyle;
            int attackGfx;
            int attackProjectile;
            int agressivenessType;
            for(ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, channel.size()); buffer.hasRemaining(); npcCombatDefinitions.put(Integer.valueOf(npcId), new NPCCombatDefinitions(hitpoints, attackAnim, defenceAnim, deathAnim, attackDelay, deathDelay, respawnDelay, maxHit, attackStyle, attackGfx, attackProjectile, agressivenessType)))
            {
                npcId = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                hitpoints = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                attackAnim = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                defenceAnim = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                deathAnim = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                attackDelay = buffer.get() & 0xff;
                deathDelay = buffer.get() & 0xff;
                respawnDelay = buffer.getInt();
                maxHit = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                attackStyle = buffer.get() & 0xff;
                attackGfx = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                attackProjectile = buffer.getShort() & 0xffff;
                agressivenessType = buffer.get() & 0xff;
            }

            channel.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private NPCCombatDefinitionsL()
    {
    }

    private static final HashMap<Integer, NPCCombatDefinitions> npcCombatDefinitions = new HashMap<Integer, NPCCombatDefinitions>();
    private static final NPCCombatDefinitions DEFAULT_DEFINITION = new NPCCombatDefinitions(1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String PACKED_PATH = "data/npcs/packedCombatDefinitions.ncd";
}
```

The format in the text file:
http://pastebin.com/ngrECkuD

Comment: Not having a go at you here, Alex, but the correct term for that variable would be `splitLine`. The past tense of the verb "split" is actually "split" as in "I split the log yesterday". You appear to have attempted to use "splitted" which is not an English word and, in any case, you've missed a `t` which would make the base word "splite", again, not one in the English language. Anyway, totally irrelevant to the question, I'm just being a pedant :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're reading and trying to parse the String `npcId`, not the associated number represented as a String - `7344`.

You probably meant:

```
int npcId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[1]);
```

instead of:

```
int npcId = Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[0]);
```

Next time, please refer to http://sscce.org/ when writing your question.

Comment: xception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid NPC Combat Definitions line: 1, npcId - 7344

Comment: @AlexDaSilva - Because you probably reached line #14 in your input file which has 0 fields instead of the 2 you're expecting.  Time to back way-up and understand what each line of your code is doing before you continue further...

Comment: Well I think the formatting in the text file is wrong, Maybe its formatted in a different way than im putting it?

Answer (score 0):

That format that you posted is not correct. This is the format that the packer can read:

Example:
//npcId - hitpoints attackAnim defenceAnim deathAnim attackDelay deathDelay respawnDelay maxHit attackStyle attackGfx attackProjectile agressivenessType

---

> //Man - 2 << this here is to tell you what the npc is.
>
> 1 - 70 422 425 836 5 1 60 10 MELEE -1 -1 PASSIVE

---